# Iterate through an SQL Server table and insert rows

Tags: sql-server, iteration

A table (Table1) has the data below:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| AccountNo | OldBranch | NewBranch | Balance |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+
|    785321 |        10 |        20 |    -200 |
|    785322 |        10 |        20 |     300 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

Using the logic : 
if the Balance is negative (ie. <0) then NewBranch has to be debited (Dr) and Old Branch has to be credited (Cr); 
if the Balance is positive (ie. >0) then OldBranch has to be debited (Dr) and New Branch has to be credited (Cr); 
rows as below have to be inserted into another Table (Table2)

```
+------------+------+--------+--------+
| Account NO | DrCr | Branch | Amount |
+------------+------+--------+--------+
|     785321 | Dr   |     20 |    200 |
|     785321 | Cr   |     10 |    200 |
|     785322 | Cr   |     20 |    300 |
|     785322 | Dr   |     10 |    300 |
+------------+------+--------+--------+
```

What are the possible solutions using a Cursor and otherwise? 
Thanks,

Comment: Certainly not a cursor. You just need two update statements.

Comment: The question indicates that you are a software developer working on SQL. You have to forget that loops/iteration exist when thinking about SQL (they come in handy, but on rare occasions only), but think about groups and sets of data, and how you link them together. As Sean indicates, you need two update statements (possibly in a transaction) by selecting the data you need for each (one for oldbranch and one for newbranch).

Comment: Yes your mindset is stuck in the procedural world. Instead of thinking about changing rows you have to shift your thinking to what you want to do to a column.

Comment: I think all the answer below are missing the fact that four rows need to be 'created' from two rows. If the data doesn't already exist this is not an update statement, it's a `CROSS JOIN` (or `INNER JOIN`) to generate the rows and an `INSERT` to put them in the table. Perhaps the OP could confirm before I pose an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide much in the way of details but something like this should be pretty close.

```
update nb
set Balance = Balance - ABS(t1.Balance)
from NewBranch nb
join Table1 t1 on t1.AccountNo = nb.AccountNo
where nb.Balance < 0

update ob
set Balance = Balance - ABS(t1.Balance)
from OldBranch ob
join Table1 t1 on t1.AccountNo = ob.AccountNo
where ob.Balance > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely dont need a cursor, just a set of insert statements

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (AccountNo,DrCr,Branch,Amount) 
SELECT AccountNo,'Dr',IIF(Balance<0,NewBranch,OldBranch),IIF(balance<0,-1*balance,balance) FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT AccountNo,'Cr',IIF(Balance>0,NewBranch,OldBranch),IIF(balance<0,-1*balance,balance) FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Accountno int,
                  OldBranch INT,
                  NewBranch int,
                  Balance int)
insert into @t (Accountno,
               OldBranch,
               NewBranch,
               Balance)
values (785321,10,20,200),
       (785322,10,20,300)

select Accountno,Y.CRDR,Y.Branch,Y.Amount from @t CROSS APPLY 
(Select 'Dr' AS CRDR,OldBranch AS Branch,Balance As Amount 
       UNION ALL 

   Select 'Cr',NewBranch,Balance)y
```